# Why does md-select binds two value to its ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a md-select implementation that have two fields which is binded to an object array having many fields. However the distinguishing fields are `year` and `quarter`. An object is identified on the basis of its year and quarter, which will always be unique.

```
<md-input-container>
                        <label>Quarter/Year</label>
                        <md-select ng-model="sc.selection.quarter" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.quarter'}" >
                            <div>
                                <md-option ng-value="q" ng-repeat="q in sc.quarters track by $index">{{"Q " + q.quarter + "  /  " + q.year}}</md-option>
                            </div>
                        </md-select>
                    </md-input-container>
```

I have the above code right now. But with this code it displays 2 same quarters of different years selected in the input box. however there really is only one quarter in JS model.

I tried changing as :

```
ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.quarter && $value.year'}"
```

This still has the issue. Now it shows quarter 3 and quarter 4 of the same year selected in the box.

How do I resolve this issue and can have the accurate quarter selected always. Could not find any help from any forums on this.

Edit: To add to the question, my md-select is not having the `multiple` attribute, which makes it more weird to display two selected fields

Comment: post the json! btw saurabh tiwari cricketer

Comment: will post in a while

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/gLeRKm?editors=1010#0) example that tries to reflect your question. Maybe it will help you.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Quarter/Year</label>
    <md-select ng-model="sc.selection.quarter">
      <div>
        <md-option ng-value="q" ng-repeat="q in sc.quarters track by $index">{{"Q " + q.quarter + "  /  " + q.year}}</md-option>
      </div>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
  <p>{{sc.selection.quarter}}</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sc = {
    quarters: [
      {quarter: 1, year: 2016},
      {quarter: 2, year: 2016},
      {quarter: 3, year: 2016},
      {quarter: 4, year: 2016}
      {quarter: 1, year: 2017},
      {quarter: 2, year: 2017},
      {quarter: 3, year: 2017},
      {quarter: 4, year: 2017}
    ]
  };
});
```

Comment: Your codepen replicates the issue in a different way. Here I cant see two fields binding, but If I select Q1/2016, it binds Q1/2017

Comment: But whats the resolution for this problem, when the binding is based on two properties of object

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari Could you explain what you mean by "If I select Q1/2016, it binds Q1/2017"?

Comment: Go to your code and select option `Quarter 1 Year 2016`, and look what gets bound to the model

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari I've updated the CodePen and answer by removing the `ng-model-options` and the selection works. Would that work for you?

Comment: Your code now obviously is the basic usage of md-select, which works fine. Unfortunately in my use case I need to bind values out of the `ng-repeat` array and hence I need to use 'ng-model-options`

Comment: The only solution I see then is to assign a distinct property like `id` to each `quarter` field.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari You could do this - `ng-model-options="{trackBy: $index}"` - https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/JbvLMz?editors=1010#0